# about spring boot jdbctemple multi datasources reuse common config

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I used spring boot + jdbctemplate, and in my business I have to access multi datasource, e.g.

application.properties

```
foo.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/foo
foo.datasource.username=root
foo.datasource.password=12345678

bar.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/bar
bar.datasource.username=root
bar.datasource.password=12345678
```

Java Config

```
@Bean(name = "fooDb")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo.datasource")
public DataSource fooDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
@Bean(name = "fooJdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate fooJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("fooDb") DataSource ds) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
}
```

and there are some common configuration for all datasources

```
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=30000
spring.datasource.validation-query=select 1
```

How could I populate these common properties to every jdbctemplate, e.g.

```
@Bean(name = "commonDb")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public DataSource commonDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Comment: just use a properties bean with a specified config class, i.e. `CommonDataConfig` and inject that bean into the other configuration class?

Answer (score 0):

Now my way is

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.test-while-idle}")
private boolean  testWhileIdle;
@Value("${spring.datasource.time-between-eviction-runs-millis}")
private int timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis;
@Value("${spring.datasource.validation-query}")
private String validationQuery;


private DataSource commonProcess(DataSource build) {
    org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = (org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource) build;
    ds.setTestWhileIdle(testWhileIdle);
    ds.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis);
    ds.setValidationQuery(validationQuery);

    return build;
}


@Bean(name = "fooDb")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo.datasource")
public DataSource fooDataSource() {
    return commonProcess(DataSourceBuilder.create().build());
}
```